# Website SVN user authentication

Tags: svn, coldfusion, web

**Problem**:
Many users on our website do not have accounts for our SVN repository. Whenever we create a link to an SVN document using markup like this:

```
<a href="https://documentURL/document.pdf">View Document</a>
```

users who click the link must enter authentication information into a pop-up dialog box.

**Our solution**:
We have created a limited access account with read-only capabilities for certain documents. We integrated the Java SVNKit library into our ColdFusion website and we log in to SVN using our limited access account credentials.

**Help needed**:
Being logged-in to SVN with the limited access account does not prevent the authentication dialog box from appearing. Is there any way to prevent this dialog box from appearing while still only giving users the access level of our limited access account?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look at [Sventon](http://sventon.org). Sventon is a web-based Subversion browser which will do much of what you need. For example, you can set it up, so the Sventon will log into a valid account and allow users of Sventon read-only access.

You can also setup Sventon to allow downloads of files (this is strictly optional), so users without Subversion access can download the files. (This is **not** checking out the files since this creates no working directory or allows you to make changes).

Sventon works with software like Jira and Jenkins which might be exactly what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Anonymous SVN access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080698/allow-anonymous-access-to-parts-of-a-secured-subversion-repository)?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This is a great solution in many cases; however, we have secure/classified documents in our repository and the users access them through a secure website. In this case I don't think we want any anonymous access to SVN. We do want the users to be authenticated through our limited access account which is password protected. The thing is, the user's who access documents via the website may not have their own account in our SVN. That is why we would like the website to authenticate the user behind the scenes so they don't have to worry about SVN's user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cfcontent` to grab the file and serve it up. You can wrap any coldfusion logic around the `cfcontent` call to protect your classified documents.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank everyone for their help on this. I have found the solution. In the URL you are able to enter the authentication information in the following format: http://user:password@server:80/path

Read more about it here: http://www.rojotek.com/blog/2008/05/19/http-authentication-in-a-url/